# writing a if-else-then fucntion

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to call a function from a package, snippets as below:

```
library(optionstrat)

# sameple detla 
# do not run 
# calldelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
# putdelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)

x=10
sigma=0.25
t=0.25
r=0.05

delta<-function(option_type,stock_price) { 
    if (option_type="c") {
        delta<-calldelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
    } else {
        delta<-putdelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
    }
}
```

both calldelta and putdelta are built in functions from optionstrat package, and I would like to write a function so that if option_type="c", then return with a call delta value based on the stock price input. Likewise, if option_type!="c", then return with a put delta value based on the stock price input.

My end goal here is to come up with a function like delta(c,10) then return with a call delta value based on stock price 10. May I know how should I do from here? Thanks.

Update 1:

Now I try working with the below snippets:

```
x=10
sigma=0.25
t=0.25
r=0.05

stock_delta<-function(option_type,s) { 
    if (option_type="c") {
        delta<-calldelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
    } else {
        delta<-putdelta(s,x,sigma,t,r)
    }
}
```

And again, if I define optiontype equals to c & s equals to 10, the same warning msg is returned...

Update 2:

Thanks to @akrun, now the function is created & now I would like to add one more return value from the delta function by adding:

```
calleval(s,x,sigma,t,r)$Gamma
puteval(s,x,sigma,t,r)$Gamma
```

The first line will return with the call gamma value & the latter will return with put gamma. May I know how do I string it with the function written previously?

Comment: you need `==` and not `=` in `if`.  In addition, there is no `stock_price` used within the function

Comment: @akren, I changed to `==` and run `delta(c,10)` & return with warning msg like this: In if (option_type == "c") delta <- calldelta(s, x, sigma, t, r) else delta <- putdelta(s,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: What is `stockprice` input in the function which is used in the inner functions.  Please show the input `s`..  If you are caling `delta(c, 10)`, the `c` is not a character string.  You may need `delta("c", 10)` and also change the argument to `s` instead of `stock_price`  and if I call `delta("c", 10)#
[1] 0.5645439`

Comment: if you're using delta as a function name, you may not want to use delta as a variable name

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover, thanks, i changed  to `delta` to `stock_delta`

Comment: `delta<-function(option_type,stock_price)
{

 if (option_type=="c")
    calldelta(stock_price,x,sigma,t,r)
else
    putdelta(stock_price,x,sigma,t,r)
}` and then `delta("c", 10)`  Your function didn't return anything.  It was assigned to `delta`

Comment: @akrun, thanks I tried. Nothing returns after I do  `delta("c",10)`..

Comment: @Bubbles I posted the code as a solution.  Maybe the code in the comment didn't had the linebreaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the function - 1) function arguments passed should match the arguments to the inner function, 2)  `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison operator, 3) if the last statement is assigned to an object, it wouldn't print on the console.  We may either need to `return(delta)` or in this case there is no need to create an object `delta` inside (when the function name is also the same), 4) Passing unquoted argument (`c`) checks for object name `c` and even have an additional issue as `c` is also a function name.  Instead, pass a string "c" as is expected in the `if` condition

```
delta<-function(option_type,stock_price)
{

 if (option_type=="c")
    calldelta(stock_price,x,sigma,t,r)
else
    putdelta(stock_price,x,sigma,t,r)
}
```

-testing

```
> delta("c", 10)
[1] 0.5645439
```

Comment: thank you , it works perfectly now. Just accepted your answer :)